# How to count the mount of times an object with a specific key value pair exists in a JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am relatively new at PHP, I am trying to figure out how to count the mount of times an object with a specific key value pair(e.g. "name": "John Amos") exists in a JSON array using PHP and echoing it. Below is my JSON data.

```
{
    "main": {
        "request": "40"
    },
    "data": {
        "page": 1,
        "posts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "John Amos",
                "used_id": "A001",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Ugon Charles",
                "used_id": "A007",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Mary Ann",
                "used_id": "A004",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "name": "Mary Ann",
                "used_id": "A004",
                "info": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "John Amos",
                "used_id": "A001",
                "info": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste"
            
            },
            {
                "id": "6",
                "name": "John Amos",
                "used_id": "A001",
                "info": "Ut enim ad minima veniam"
            
            }
            
            
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried something like this;

```
$uid_counts = array_count_values($data['data']['posts']);
$username = $uid_counts['John Amos'];
echo $uid_counts;
```

Comment: Please post the code of what you already tried.

Comment: Use `array_count_values` together with `array_column($data['data']['posts'], 'name')`. array_count_values doesn't work on array members that are arrays. What you tried above should have thrown a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function countPost(array $arr,$key,$val){
  $count=0;
  foreach($arr as $ar){
    if($ar[$key]==$val){
       $count++;
     }
  }
  return $count;
}

$uid_counts = countPost($data['data']['posts'],'name','John Amos');
echo $uid_counts;
```

i have not tested the code but you got my idea. try it, it should solve your problem